# Zend Validate Email Address and Deep MX Checking

Tags: php, email, zend-framework, dns, mx-record

I have started using `Zend_Validate_EmailAddress` with the `mx` and `deep` options set to true. I think I am getting some false negatives when it comes to MX records that have IP addresses in the reserved IP ranges.

A good example is the [MX records for harn.ufl.edu](http://dnsquery.org/dnsquery/harn.ufl.edu/MX). It appear that it's failing because of IP addresses in the 128.0.0.0/16 range. It does however have one record that uses 8.6.245.30, which is not in the reserved range.

Another example is the [MX record for martinhealth.org](http://dnsquery.org/dnsquery/martinhealth.org/MX). It's MX record domain uses 198.136.38.2.

Is this a case of something that's technically incorrect but actually works?

Comment: Do you use it with Windows? _Within Windows environments MX checking is only available when PHP 5.3 or above is used. Below PHP 5.3 MX checking will not be used even if it's activated within the options._

Comment: It looks like you encountered a bug in `Zend_Validate_EmailAddress`.  The only reserved IP addresses in the `128.` range are from `128.0.0.0` - `128.0.255.255`.  The mail server for harn is not in this range, but it appears Zend_Validate_Email is incorrectly calculating something with the subnet mask causing a false positive.  I'll see if I can find out more.

Comment: If you are around soon, I set up this [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9213/zend-validate-emailaddress) to discuss the issue, I believe I see where the problem in ZF is.

Comment: @drew010 - I found the issue too, and rewrote the part of the validator. I will be posting my solution, and welcome any criticism of the approach that I took.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments on my post allude, there is a bug in `Zend_Validate_EmailAddress::_isReserved`. Not only is it buggy, but it's difficult to understand the logic flow. It was a `private` function, so I changed it to `protected` so I could override it in my sub-class. There were also some incorrect ranges in the `$_invalidIp` array.

For my logic check, I decided that the simplest (clearest?) way to compare IP addresses was to convert them to their decimal integer equivalents.

Here's my sub-class:

```
class My_Validate_EmailAddressDeep extends Zend_Validate_EmailAddress
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_messageTemplates = array(
        self::INVALID            => "Invalid type given. String expected",
        self::INVALID_FORMAT     => "'%value%' is not a valid email address in the basic [user]@[hostname] format",
        self::INVALID_HOSTNAME   => "The '%hostname%' part of '%value%' is not a valid hostname",
        self::INVALID_MX_RECORD  => "'%hostname%' does not appear to be configured to accept email",
        self::INVALID_SEGMENT    => "'%hostname%' does not appear to be configured to accept external email",
        self::DOT_ATOM           => null,
        self::QUOTED_STRING      => null,
        self::INVALID_LOCAL_PART => "The '%localPart%' part of '%value%' is not valid",
        self::LENGTH_EXCEEDED    => "'%value%' is longer than the allowed length for an email address",
    );

    /**
     * Internal options array
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_options = array(
        'allow' => Zend_Validate_Hostname::ALLOW_DNS,
        'deep' => true,
        'domain' => true,
        'hostname' => null,
        'mx' => true,
    );

    /**
     * @see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses#Reserved_IPv4_addresses
     * @var array [first octet] => [[CIDR] => [[range start], [range end]]]
     */
    protected $_reservedIps = array(
        '0' => array('0.0.0.0/8' => array('0.0.0.0', '0.255.255.255',),),
        '10' => array('10.0.0.0/8' => array('10.0.0.0', '10.255.255.255',),),
        '127' => array('127.0.0.0/8' => array('127.0.0.0', '127.255.255.255',),),
        '169' => array('169.254.0.0/16' => array('169.254.0.0', '169.254.255.255',),),
        '172' => array('172.16.0.0/12' => array('172.16.0.0', '172.31.255.255',),),
        '192' => array(
            '192.0.2.0/24' => array('192.0.2.0', '192.0.2.255',),
            '192.88.99.0/24' => array('192.88.99.0', '192.88.99.255',),
            '192.168.0.0/16' => array('192.168.0.0', '192.168.255.255',),
        ),
        '198' => array(
            '198.18.0.0/15' => array('198.18.0.0', '198.19.255.255',),
            '198.51.100.0/24' => array('198.51.100.0', '198.51.100.255',),
        ),
        '203' => array('203.0.113.0/24' => array('203.0.113.0', '203.0.113.255',),),
        '224' => array('224.0.0.0/4' => array('224.0.0.0', '239.255.255.255',),),
        '240' => array('240.0.0.0/4' => array('240.0.0.0', '255.255.255.255',),),
    );

    /**
     * Returns if the given host is reserved
     *
     * @param string $host
     * @return boolean
     */
    protected function _isReserved($host)
    {
        if (!preg_match('/^([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$/', $host)) {
            $host = gethostbyname($host);
        }

        $octets = explode('.', $host);
        if (224 <= (int) $octets[0]) {
            // IP Addresses beginning with 224 or greater are all reserved, short-circuit range checks
            return true;
        } elseif (array_key_exists($octets[0], $this->_reservedIps)) {
            // for integer comparisons
            $intIp = $this->_ipToInt($host);

            // loop over reserved IP addresses
            foreach ($this->_reservedIps as $ranges) {
                foreach ($ranges as $range) {
                    if (($this->_ipToInt($range[0]) <= $intIp)
                            && ($this->_ipToInt($range[1]) >= $intIp)) {
                        // the IP address falls in a reserved range
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }

            // the IP address did not fall in a reserved range
            return false;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Convert a dot-decimal IP address to it's decimal integer equivalent
     *
     * @param string $ip
     * @return integer
     */
    protected function _ipToInt($ip)
    {
        $octets = explode('.', $ip);
        foreach ($octets as $key => $octet) {
            $octets[$key] = str_pad(decbin($octet), 8, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
        }
        $bin = implode('', $octets);
        return bindec($bin);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have finally filed a bug in the Zend Framework issue tracker: http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-12160