# Zend Framework Emailaddress Validator check if email address is legal

Tags: php, email, zend-framework, email-validation

I am using Zend Framework Version 1.12. We are using the `Zend_Validate_Emailaddress` validator. I see lots of options on the API about checking MX Records.

What I am curious is how do we ensure that **not only is the emailaddress correct by punctuation, but also is validated that it IS A LEGAL EMAILADDRESS**.

How do I handle this using `Zend_Validate_Emailaddress`.

Here's some references that I am looking at,

[Stack ZF Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824449/zend-validate-email-address-and-deep-mx-checking)

[ZF API](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.validate.set.html#zend.validate.set.email_address.options)

Comment: Only way to fully validate an email address is send an email with a link for the user to click to validiate it.

Comment: Send an email with a unique key and make the user enter it on your website

Comment: The above comments are true, but you also know that anything that's not a valid address and does not have a reachable `MX` (or `A` fallback) host is not a working address, so it's still a worthwhile check. Testing by connecting is generally useless these days as many hosts now accept anything and send rejections later.